# VHDL: How to verify that a signal has remained unchanged over a period of time in VHDL testbench?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL testbench we can use the wait statement and then check the value of signal after arbitrary intervals of time. It is straight forward to do this. This can be used to check value of something at specific points in time.

I am in a sitauation where I not only need to check value of a signal but also ensure that is has remained constant since it was checked last time. How can this be done in a VHDL testbench? I do not think VHDL has a built in fuctionality to do something like this.

Comment: Just a thought.. could you connect your signal of interest to a latch or a counter of some sort? You can tell if the signal hasn't changed if the counter hasn't incremented

Comment: @crossroad Sounds like an easy and obvious solution. Testbench is exactly that - you add the stuff into it that needed to test what you want to test.

Comment: there is also a built-in `finish`, `stop` and `assert` procedures in VHDL. You can invoke these once you detect some value. https://vhdlwhiz.com/how-to-stop-testbench/

Comment: Predefined attributes of signals 'STABLE and 'QUIET are boolean signals that take static arguments of type time. The former determines there has been no transactions.

Comment: So, when is this check happening? What triggers this checking....

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do this with a VHDL process. The sensitivity list of a VHDL process basically says "re-run this process whenever any of these signal change", so the process itself is a level-change detector. Just add logic into the process to start/stop or latch an error status bit high.

Comment: There are attributes 'last_event and 'last_transaction to access the time of the most recent event or transaction on that signal. Surely these are exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: @mitu raj, the test process is like this, e.g check_value(); wait for 100 ns; check_value(); I can check the value before the 100 ns period starts and after it ends, but I also need to guarantee that the value has remained static during the 100 ns period.

Comment: Sittin Hawk has given the most obvious answer which is how I intended to do this. However, that means I have to create another process to monitor the signal. I will look into the method given by user_1818839

Comment: Hopefully this is the last update. I found the 'last_event attribute. I have found no attribute called 'last_transaction. I used 'last_event but it did not give the expected value. Long story short, it seems that the solution is to use the 'stable attribute.

Comment: `wait for 100 ns; assert xyz'stable(100 ns) report "ok..." severity info;` -- Something like this perhaps on the signal of interest `xyz`?